# Customize the has_many through relationship name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having these models in my application:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

But Recipe model already has had a text field with same name `ingredients`, so this setting `has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients` should be changed.
How can I change the name `ingredients` to somethings(`ingredient_items`) else by using `source` or `as`?

Comment: The underlying problem here is defining what the difference between the Ingredient model and the ingredients text field is. What are you storing in the ingredients text field that isn't stored in the Ingredient model? You may then find yourself asking: "Do I need the text field?" to which I imagine the answer is now. After that, you can say: "What is the difference betewen an RecipeIngredient and an Ingredient? Do they need to be two different models?

Comment: @benjessop yes you almost right, ingredients text field has its own functionality, so the problem is I should keep as it is.

Comment: Thanks @Eyeslandic, it was easy but my brain is so bad :D

Answer (score 1):

using `source` - you can name the association whatever you want (in your example you mentioned `ingredient_items`) then specify what source, the source being the association present in the model your current association goes through in you case the model is `recipe_ingredients` and the `association` is `:ingredient`

```rb
has_many :ingredient_items, source: :ingredient, through: :recipe_ingredients
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching my brain, this works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

you can also give this a try:

```
has_many :items, class_name: "Ingredient"
```

Comment: Thanks let me try!